# Are temporary files deleted while creating a docker image from a DockerFile?

Tags: docker

So, I am trying to create a docker image from a DockerFile. It involves copying a 10 GB binary file inside the docker image. Due to some connectivity issues, my download stopped after 90% for a total of 3 times. After each time, I would simply run the `docker build` command again.

I am not sure if docker will delete the old files on its own. Or have I now used about 30GB space?

I am using Windows 10 with Hyper-V.

Answer (score 0):

Tempfiles are in the TEMP directory. Docker, as any other well written application removes its temp files after use.

Of course, when not regurlarly ended, things can go wrong. If unsure, check your TEMP directory, you should be able to see files from 10 GB from a specific time and date.

As specified, the docker daemon cleans up all traces of the build process when it loses contact with the docker client for any reason.